# IIS rewrite still active eventhough it is disabled

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I have this iis site for which I have added some rewrite rules.

The rewrite rule itself is simple If I access the site [www.a.com](http://www.a.com) rewrite/redirect to [www.b.com](http://www.b.com)

and redirect subpages to corresponding subpages on [www.b.com](http://www.b.com)

So have via IIS manager setup some rewrite rules.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
            <match l=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" l="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_I}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="https://shop.a.com/5e/     ->  https://www.b.com/products/5/" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
            <match l="https://shop.a.com/5e/" />
            <action type="Redirect" l="https://www.b.com/products/5/" logRewrittenl="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="https://shop.a.com/5e/     ->  https://www.b.com/products/5/" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
            <match l="https://shop.a.com/5e/" />
            <action type="Redirect" l="https://www.b.com/products/5/" logRewrittenl="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="https://shop.a.com/10e/ -> https://www.b.com/products/10/" enabled="false" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
            <match l="https://shop.a.com/10e/" />
            <action type="Redirect" l="https://www.b.com/products/10/" logRewrittenl="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="https://shop.a.com/16e/  -> https://www.b.com/products/16/" enabled="false" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
            <match l="https://shop.a.com/16e/" />
            <action type="Redirect" l="https://www.b.com/products/16/" logRewrittenl="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="https://shop.a.com/3e/     ->  https://www.b.com/products/3/" enabled="false" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
            <match l="https://shop.a.com/3e/" />
            <action type="Redirect" l="https://www.b.com/products/3/" logRewrittenl="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

prior to this I had a rewrite that rewrote shop.a.com to [www.b.com](http://www.b.com)

This one should not be active anymore, but for somereason is this still active, and all the other rules listed here does not seem to work.

When I access shop.a.com/5e I enter [www.b.com](http://www.b.com).

The network tab in chrome states that the url is being redirected to [www.b.com](http://www.b.com), but have no idea where this redirect is listed if not in the web.config?

the url mentioned here are only examples and not the actual sites being managed.

Any idea on why this redirect is doing this?

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used regex match instead which made it work.
The exact matching via iis did not work as expected.